# Vue.js - Inject el elements to html

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have website for online tests.
One of the question that i have created on the test its topic "Fill in the blank", which means fill in the blank spaces words.

The question comes from the server as a string like that `"Today is a [1] day, and i should [2] today"`.
What i want to do is to get that string and replace all the `[]` with `el-input`.

I have done something like that

```
<template>
 <div class="d-flex flex-column mg-t-20 pd-10">
 <h6 class="tx-gray-800">Fill in the blank areas the missing words</h6>
 <div class="mg-t-20" v-html="generateFillBlankQuestion(question.question)" />
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
   name: 'FillBlank',
   directives: {},
   props: [ 'question' ],
   components: {
   },
   computed: {},
   data() {
     return {
       input: ''
     }
   },
   filters: {},
   created() { 
   },
   methods: {
       generateFillBlankQuestion(question) {
        var matches = question.match((/\[\d\]/g))
        console.log(matches)
        matches.forEach((element) => {
          console.log(element)
         
         question = question.replace(element, '<el-input />')
       })
       console.log(question)
       return question
      } 
   }
 }
```

On this line `question = question.replace(element, '<el-input />')` I'm replacing the [] to input.
For some reason when i try to replace it to `<el-input>` it doesn't render it.
But if i use `<input type='text'>` it renders it.
Is it possible to inject `el elements`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the Vue run-time template compiler you can not render Vue components inside `v-html`. You should do something like this:

```html
<template>
 <div class="d-flex flex-column mg-t-20 pd-10">
   <h6 class="tx-gray-800">Fill in the blank areas the missing words</h6>
   <div class="mg-t-20">
     <template v-for="(word,idx) in wordList">
       <el-input v-if="word.blank" v-model="word.value" :key="idx" />
       <template v-else>{{ word.text }}</template>
     </template>
   </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default 
{
   name: 'FillBlank',
   props: 
   { 
     question:
     {
       type: String,
       default: ''
     }
   },
   computed: 
   {
     wordList()
     {
       const words = this.question.split(' ');
       return words.map(word =>
       ({
         value: '',
         text: word,
         blank: /^\[\d+\]$/.test(word),
       }));
     }
   }
 }
```